# Test to see if object exists in R

Tags: r, object

Is there an easy way to see if an object exists in R? I would love a function that returns TRUE if the object has been defined and FALSE if the object has not been defined. Thus far, everything I try returns

```
Error: object 'asdf' not found
```

I want a function that returns TRUE if the argument exists (e.g., does.exist(asdf) ) and returns FALSE if it does not exist.

Any ideas if there is such a thing or how I would make it?

Comment: It does not return an error, it returns `FALSE` in that case, as documented.

Comment: Aha. The issue was that I was omitting quotation marks.